# Macbook Air freezes on macOS Big Sur but not on Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

So it was all working fine until yesterday when my MacBook Air (2017 Model) started to freeze few minutes after login; I had to force shutdown as nothing else worked.

So I went ahead and booted in recovery mode and formatted the internal ssd and proceeded with internet recovery which installed macOS Catalina which I updated to Big Sur. This again started to freeze few minutes after login.

> After that I installed *Ubuntu 20.04* which as of now shows no sign of
> freeze or hang even hours after use. What could be the issue? Any
> suggestions.

- Hardware Test - Pass
- did SMC, PRAM reset, safe mode boot - no avail

Comment: Do you see any files in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` that end in `.crash`, `.hang`, `.panic`, or `.spin`? (You may first have to enable file extensions in the Finder: Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Show all filename extensions.) If so, can you update your question with their names?

Comment: Also can you boot back into recovery and run Disk First Aid on your boot volume? I know you recently formatted it but in case of undetected hardware damage you may be re-corrupting your volume. Small chance but I've seen it happen.